# Mysql query of 200000 rows and performace

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i have build a custom cms on php/mysql and bootstrap.
Speed is pretty decent under 0.2s load time.
But i want to implement a feature to get user ip and see if it listed on the database which will have 200000 ips in rows and im afraid of speed drop.
Any suggestion for me please, or should i do it via json or?
Thank you

Comment: How often are you planning on checking ips? IP addresses can fairly easily be converted into a 32-bit number for storage/comparison. If indexed, 200k values should be searchable in no more than 18 "comparisons".

Comment: if its indexed the search will take only a fraction of a second

Comment: i hope you know IP !=person, not sure why your matching the visitors IP  to a db, its some what unusual

Comment: 200000 is nothing, But you may improve it with indexes

Comment: for every visitor, i want to comprare if his ip is on the list

Comment: i understand what you are saying @uueerdo but im cont sure of the 18 "comparisons" part, can you please explain

Comment: General sorting techniques result in logarithmic/binary search; simplified... checks the middle, then goes up or down half from there, repeat. This means it can generally be determined if a value is present with log2(# of values) comparisons. _you can find a specific number in a collection of all 32-bit numbers in 32 steps_

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see engine and index(es).  Please provide the `SELECT` that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Don't do `WHERE INET_NTOA(ip_column) = $input_value`; flip it around:  `WHERE ip_column = INET_ATON($input_value)` and index `ip_column`.